# Sharepoint Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column

I have two SP lists a source(Demo Lookup List) and a target(Demo list).
[image]

[image]

The project column in Demo List is the lookup column source in Demo Lookup List giving the title values.
when in edit mode if we click on the cell below the project column, it should only show the value equal to Project/Operations value corresponding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I understand that when you click the Project column cell it should only show the value which is equal to Project/Operations column otherwise it should not give any value in Project column.

Per my knowledge, there is no option to achieve this requirement. Lookup column will return all values from source list.